# kubernetes not connecting to docker hub

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-registry

Alright, so I am trying to publish a private docker image to kubernetes, and I am running into some odd issues.

I start of with logging into docker

```
docker login -u $DOCKER_USER -p $DOCKER_TOKEN
```

and that will store my password in a config file for me, so I run this

```
kubectl create secret generic regcred --from-file=/root/.docker/config.json --type=kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson
```

I would expect that to pick up the url in the `config.json` file, but I get this error

```
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

So I thought that I might as well specify the server

```
kubectl create secret generic regcred --from-file=/root/.docker/config.json --type=kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson --server=https://index.docker.io/v1/
```

But still no luck.

```
error: EOF
2020-01-12T19:45:39.7433187Z stdout P Please enter Username:
```

and since this is running on a build server, I cannot enter the username.

So what am I missing here?

Comment: Hi, what is your infrastructure? Could You check by `kubectl get all -A` if your cluster is working properly? Can You create any pod by using kubectl run/create or the same problem occurs? Maybe try create a secret by providing credentials on the [command line](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/#create-a-secret-by-providing-credentials-on-the-command-line)?

Answer (score 0):

> `kubectl create secret generic regcred --from-file=/root/.docker/config.json --type=kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson --server=https://index.docker.io/v1/`

You are conflating the `--server=` argument to `kubectl`, which determines the kubernetes server to which it will connect, with [`--docker-server=`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#-em-secret-docker-registry-em-)

You will want to use the provided `kubectl create secret docker-registry` command (versus the `generic` type) because the `Secret` that is created by the specialized version is **not** just the `.docker/config.json` file uploaded to the cluster -- they are structurally different

Also:

> The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?

is a dead giveaway that you do not have a correctly configured kubeconfig so you can forget about any `kubectl` command doing anything reasonable until you fix that problem